# How do i access the array property of this nested object using map function?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern

I have an object with array properties that I am getting from Mongodb database. The backend setup is correct because I am able to get the output in console. But I am making some mistake in displaying this data in the desired table format.

```
{Array.isArray(lights)
                ? Object.values(lights).map((light, key) => (
                    <TableRow
                      key={key}
                      sx={{ "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": { border: 0 } }}
                    >
                      <TableCell>{light.name}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{light.status}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  ))
                : null}
```

This is the structure of the object I am getting in console[Screenshot of console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sKp2.png)

How to I get the values of name and status rendered in the table using map function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I access and process nested objects, arrays, or JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Object.values` ​​- not needed here:

```
Array.isArray(lights) ? lights.map((light, key) => ( ...
```

Comment: I tried this but it isn't working

Comment: Please provide the full text of the error message or a screenshot.